# Why are magnets made in only a few shapes?

Tags: electromagnetism

Additionally, why are all magnets solid? For example, why can't a magnet be made in the shape of a PVC pipe (very long tube)?

Answer (score 0):

It can. Just search online and you can buy magnets as tubes, balls, cubes etc.

Answer (score 0):

They can be made of any shapes. Shapes usually we see are common because of the worldwide standard that is useful in installation and efficiency. :)